# Riemann-dash not showing anything

Tags: monitoring, riemann, riemann-dashboard

I am new to riemann. I am facing an issue which i guess would be trivial but not able to find the solution. I am not getting any data on the riemann dashboard. I have followed the exact steps said in riemann.io/howto.html
[My riemann.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u55qw.png)

[localhost:4567 page content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k5Gx.png)

Can anyone tell how to get things started.
i even did

`sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5555`
and got one entry for tcp and one entry for udp. Because of low reputation points cant upload more links for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first put an expression in your config that prints statements and then indexes them:

```
(streams 
   ...
   prn
   index
   ...)
```

and make sure they are getting indexed.

then add a graph to your dash showing the service "riemann index size" and make sure that this index which exists by default is getting to dash and that it has a non-zero number.

the events really are not getting to dash, then connect with any of the clients and make sure you can run queries. I prefer the python client for this because it has a nice CLI for doing this from the terminal.

always check the box in the upper right of the Riemann dash and make sure it has the correct server name. I have also had to configure riemann to bind to 0.0.0.0:5556 before it would accept queries when it was not running on the same host or when it was running on the same host though in a docker container.

and last of all, consider moving to something other than dash for graphing these things as people often out-grow it quickly anyway.